# I want to analyze transistor transient characteristics. What should I do first?

Tags: transistors, switching, transient

It's a new task for me, so I want to ask more experienced engineers. I make a "soft-start" circuit for laser driver. And I got more problems with transients. This circuit must be works like aperiodic link with slow current increase. I don't know how to proceed for mathematical computations of tranisients in bipolar transistor. What I have to do at the beginning?
[image]

This is my circuit.

Comment: Once you switch it on, it will never go off again because the gate of Q1 will be floating. Additional 12 V battery, I would use an NMOS so I don't need the 12 V. When using an NMOS then I do not need Q4, I'd use an NMOS instead of Q4.

Comment: @FakeMoustache if I use NMOS instead Q4 then time-delay circuit (R4,R4,C1) must be controls a gate of NMOS (for slow step response)?

Answer (score 1):

Q1 works as a switch. The gate should be connected to ground with a fairly large value resistor (10k-100k), so when you turn of the switch the gate charge will dissipate and close the transistor.

Now. About the BJT. It all depends on how accurate you want to get. Basically when the switch is on, R4 and R5 form form a voltage divider charging C1 to 2.5V (half of the voltage of B1). This is a simple example of an RC Vc = Vin * (1 - e^(-t/RC)), or in this particular case the Vin = 2.5V and R = R4 || R5.

Since the load is in the emitter, the circuit acts as an emitter follower, the emitter voltage will be about 0.6V lower than that on the base. If base voltage is below 0.6V you may assume the laser to be off. Above that the voltage on the emitter will be Ve = 2.5*(1-e^(-t/(5e3*10e-12)))-0.6. The voltage on your laser will depend on voltage drop on R6 and the current flowing through it.

However, this is a rather poor circuit, the maximum voltage on Ve will be around 1.9V, meaning that 60% of the power will be dissipated on the transistor (the rest on R6 and the laser). The circuit would perform much better R5 would be removed. Then the emitter would go all the way to about 4.4V.

All these calculations assume that the transistor Beta is rather large and the base current is not that significant to influence the RC constant.

Comment: thank you for advice. In the first version of my circuit I didn't use R5, but capacitance in base (C1) is not discharged when I turned off the circuit (with help of Q1). So, I added R5 to my circuit

Comment: Well then make R5 around 1M. It will discharge C1 fast and allow you to get a much greater output voltage. If you want to use an NMOS instead of a BJT remember that the gate voltage will have to be above the threshold voltage Vth to even start working. Since a typical Vth is high and varies a lot even for one transistor model (2-4V) and your supply is 5V, you'll get very little on the output (mosfet source terminal).  You could use a PMOS and put the load in the drain (as it is commonly done) and inverse the RC. You'd get much better efficiency and you'd need a switch, 2 resistors and cap.

Comment: I will be use BJT, but one moment disquiets me. I understand that this circuit works like an emitter follower and I understand the behavior of output voltage. But the critical parameter for laser is value of current and its transients. In emitter follower the current gain is much more than 1. I don't understand how to predict the behavior of current transients in that case

Comment: If you are worried about current transients (i.e. you wish to control the current) than you could use something like this (http://www.radio-electronics.com/images/transistor-constant-current-circuit-01.gif). Vb is determined by R1 and R2. Ve is (roughly) Vb-0.6. If you put a resistor of known value as Re, that the current through it will be (Vb-0.6)/Re, and will be kept constant. Since approximately Ic=Ie, the LOAD current will be constant as well. If you add a capacitor in parallel to R2, you'll get a soft start of the circuit (no sharp transient). If you need more precision than use opamps.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to realize this variant of curcuit with a help of PSpice and analyze transients